# Running into RedisTimeoutException and other exceptions with Redisson and Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure, redis, redisson

A lot of timeout exceptions and Can't add slave exceptions

#### Steps to reproduce or test case

intermittent

#### Redis version

Azure Redis Cache with 5 shards
4.0.14, 3.2.7

#### Redisson version

3.11.4

#### Redisson configuration

Default clustered config with the following overrides:
REDIS_ENABLED | true 
REDIS_KEEP_ALIVE | true 
REDIS_THREADS | 512 
REDIS_NETTY_THREADS | 1024 
REDIS_MASTER_CONNECTION_MINIMUM_IDLE_SIZE | 5 
REDIS_MASTER_CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE | 10 
REDIS_SLAVE_CONNECTION_MINIMUM_IDLE_SIZE | 5 
REDIS_SLAVE_CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE | 10
REDIS_TIMEOUT | 1000
REDIS_RETRY_INTERVAL | 500 
REDIS_TCP_NO_DELAY | true

I see following exceptions in the log:

`
exception: { [-]
     class: org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException
     thrownfrom: unknown
   }
   level: ERROR
   logger_name: org.redisson.cluster.ClusterConnectionManager
   message: Can't add slave: rediss://:15002
   process: 6523
   stack_trace: org.redisson.client.RedisTimeoutException: Command execution timeout for command: (READONLY), params: [], Redis client: [addr=rediss://:15002]
    at org.redisson.client.RedisConnection.lambda$async$1(RedisConnection.java:207)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:680)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:755)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:483)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to Redis server: /:15002
    at org.redisson.connection.pool.ConnectionPool$1.lambda$run$0(ConnectionPool.java:160)
    at org.redisson.misc.RedissonPromise.lambda$onComplete$0(RedissonPromise.java:183)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
    at org.redisson.misc.RedissonPromise.tryFailure(RedissonPromise.java:96)
    at org.redisson.connection.pool.ConnectionPool.promiseFailure(ConnectionPool.java:330)
    at org.redisson.connection.pool.ConnectionPool.lambda$createConnection$1(ConnectionPool.java:296)
    at org.redisson.misc.RedissonPromise.lambda$onComplete$0(RedissonPromise.java:183)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:570)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:549)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
    at org.redisson.misc.RedissonPromise.tryFailure(RedissonPromise.java:96)
    at org.redisson.client.RedisClient$2$1.run(RedisClient.java:240)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:510)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:518)
    at i.n.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

stack_trace: org.redisson.client.RedisTimeoutException: Unable to get connection! Try to increase 'nettyThreads' and/or connection pool size settingsNode source: NodeSource [slot=15393, addr=redis://:15007, redisClient=null, redirect=MOVED, entry=null], command: (PSETEX), params: [some key, 3600000, PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 457, cap: 512)] after 0 retry attempts
    at org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor$2.run(RedisExecutor.java:209)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:680)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:755)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:483)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

level: ERROR
   logger_name: org.redisson.cluster.ClusterConnectionManager
   message: Can't add master: rediss://:15007 for slot ranges: [[15019-15564], [12288-13652], [4096-5461]]
   process: 6574
   thread_name: redisson-netty-2-718
   timestamp: 2019-10-29 22:32:15.592

`

My logs are flooded with these exceptions and when I login to Azure portal, I see the CPU metric for Redis spiked to 100%. Any help is appreciated.